# Error gridfs with reactiveMongo 0.11.9 scala and playframework

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, reactivemongo

I'm trying to follow this example https://github.com/sgodbillon/reactivemongo-demo-app and then implement this in my project.
but I found many difficulties, because I'm using "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.11.9" not the same version used in the tutorial, I solved some problems using some imports but for this one I'm really blocked:

```
type arguments [play.api.libs.json.JsObject,Articles.this.JSONReadFile] do not conform to method find's type parameter bounds [S,T <: reactivemongo.api.gridfs.ReadFile[reactivemongo.play.json.JSONSerializationPack.type, _]](line 97)

     result <- maybeArticle.map { article =>
97        gridFS.find[JsObject, JSONReadFile]( 
98          Json.obj("article" -> article.id.get)).collect[List]().map { files =>
99          val filesWithId = files.map { file =>
```

Any help !!

Comment: I still suggest you have a look at the up-to-date [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/advanced-topics/gridfs.html) and [demo update](https://github.com/sgodbillon/reactivemongo-demo-app/pull/14).

Comment: Thank you for your help !! I tried your code but when I run my project I get this error: MongoError['The node set can not be reached! Please check your network connectivity.'

Comment: That's not related at all. I suggest you have a look at the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/tutorial/connect-database.html)